# Read in rows from a CSV using data.table's fread BY GROUP

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, fread

I have a very large CSV file containing millions and millions of rows, it is a combined dataset from multiple sources. I have a character column/variable that indicates the source of the row/observation, and I'd like to read in a subset of rows from each group using data.table's fread.

Right now I'm trying to read in 20,000 rows to test out my code but the first few million rows are all from one source so I can't get rows from multiple sources. Is there a way to say read in 20,000 rows from each SOURCE level? So basically reading in 20,000 rows from each BY GROUP (source)?

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution is to use the [vroom package](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) to read in only the "group" column, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)
df <- vroom("file.csv", col_select = group)
```

Then sample the rownumbers, grouped by group, in 'blocks':

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(rownumber = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 20000) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(rownumber)
```

Then use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801701/12957340) to select the rows in each block (one call to fread per block) and rbind them together, i.e.

```
library(data.table)
s <- df2$rownumber
v <- (1:1e5 %in% s)
idx  <- c(0, cumsum(seq$lengths))[which(seq$values)] + 1
indx <- data.frame(start=idx, length=seq$length[which(seq$values)])
result <- do.call(rbind,apply(indx,1, function(x) return(fread("test.csv",nrows=x[2],skip=x[1]))))
```

I don't have any huge files to test this, but if this approach doesn't work for you I can help troubleshoot. It might also be worth looking at an external program (e.g. AWK) as a workaround if your dataset is too large.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if doing something outside of R might be better. Using `awk` for instance, using this data in `awkgroup.csv`:

```
"something","group"
1,"A"
2,"A"
3,"A"
4,"A"
5,"A"
6,"B"
7,"B"
8,"B"
9,"B"
10,"B"
11,"C"
12,"C"
13,"C"
14,"C"
15,"C"
16,"D"
17,"D"
18,"D"
19,"D"
20,"D"
```

We can do

```sh
$ awk -F, '$2==inp{line++;if(line<3)print($0)}; $2!=inp{inp=$2;line=0;print($0)};' awkgroup.csv > newdata.csv
$ cat newdata.csv
"something","group"
1,"A"
2,"A"
3,"A"
6,"B"
7,"B"
8,"B"
11,"C"
12,"C"
13,"C"
16,"D"
17,"D"
18,"D"
```

Basic walk-through (though I do not consider myself an `awk` wizard by any account):

- `$2==inp` (and similarly `$2!=inp`) tests if the second column (our grouping variable) has changed since the previous row. The `inp` is initially uninitialized so will default to the empty string.

  **NB**: this assumes the data is ordered by-group.
- `line++;if(line<3)print($0)` is the majority of work, where it tests if `line` (our method of tracking lines within the current group) is less than `3` (we use a 0-based `line` here) and prints if so. This gives us the top 3 lines per group.
- `inp=$2;line=0;print($0)` is similar, but is run on the first line within a group; it resets the `line` counter, sets what we think the current group is by assigning to `inp`, and always prints (since this is the first line within a group).

I couldn't get this to work well in `fread(cmd="...")`, likely because it (for *some* reason) uses `shell` in lieu of the admittedly-also-broken (but not *here*) `system`. One *can* use `system` and control where the output goes, then read that normally, perhaps

```r
system2("awk", c("-F, '$2==inp{line++;if(line<3)print($0);};$2!=inp{inp=$2;line=0;print($0)};'",
                 "awkgroup.csv"),
        stdout="awkout.csv" )
fread("awkout.csv")
#     something  group
#         <int> <char>
#  1:         1      A
#  2:         2      A
#  3:         3      A
#  4:         6      B
#  5:         7      B
#  6:         8      B
#  7:        11      C
#  8:        12      C
#  9:        13      C
# 10:        16      D
# 11:        17      D
# 12:        18      D
```

FYI, `system2` is not really any better than `system`: it just concatenates the quoted (good!) `command=` with all unquoted `args` (bad!):

```r
  command <- paste(c(shQuote(command), env, args), collapse = " ")
```

which is why I'm able to cheat a little and combine all of `awk`'s `args=` into a vector.

From here, you need to control two things about this:

- change `$2` (in three places) to the column number of your grouping variable;
- change `< 3` to be whatever limit you want (recall that it is 0-based, so `< 3` gives you 3 entries, not 2).